# Sequelize object property mapping to multiple fields

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible in Sequelize.js to have a model's field be mapped to an object (hash, map, whatever) while mapping to separate DB columns? For instance, something like the following:

```js
sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        ...,
        name: {
            first: {
                field: "first_name",
                type: sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            middle: {
                field: "middle_name",
                type: sequelize.STRING
            },
            last: {
                field: "last_name",
                type: sequelize.STRING
            }
        },
        ...
    }
)
```

This would let you do things like `currentUser.name.first = "Sally"` but would map to a table with seperate columns for `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a getter method

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#defining-as-part-of-the-model-options

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  first_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  last_name: Sequelize.STRING
}, 
{
   getterMethods: {
     name: function(){ 
       return {
         first_name : this.first_name,
         last_name : this.last_name
       } 
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Ah, of course. And presumably a similar setter method for setting the name.